# How come I have an internal IP address on an android smartphone

Tags: ip

I just played around a little with the Speedtest app for android from Ookla, it shows that I have both internal and an external IP addresses. I understand that I have an external IP address which is provided to me by my cellphone provider; however, I don't understand how I have an internal IP address as I'm not connected to any private network, router etc., I'm using my 3g network.

Any idea? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The internal address is the one used by the Wifi adapter in the phone. Even if you aren't connected to a Wifi it'll be there as long as you have been since the phone was booted (it maybe there even if it isn't enabled, IDK haven't looked myself).

Answer (score 0):

The 3g network is a private network. It really is that simple.